# ant build.xml read in manifest file

Tags: java, xml, ant

How can i read in a manifest file instead of usign a xml coded manifest in my build.xml file.

This is what i have so far in my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1123523 (Stefan Sprenger)
Main-Class: studentapp.MainStart
```

And here is the workaround in my code, which i don't want to use anymore

```
<jar jarfile="jar/A12-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="studentapp.MainStart"/>
        </manifest>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant's [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task lets you specify a manifest file to use as attribute of the jar-element:

```
<jar manifest="yourfile.mf">
    <!-- other stuff -->
</jar>
```